# PHPMailer not sending to variable mailto address

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHP Mailer to automate password reset functionality (with a token) and the email is not being sent when passing the data through. It will only send if I hard code an email in the address variable. Here's a sample of the code below:

```
$link = "<a href='https://www.mywebsite.com/admin/reset-password.php?key=".$emailId."&token=".$token."'>Click To Reset password</a>";

    require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
     
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    try {
    //Server settings

    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
    $mail->Port = 25; 


    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('admin@mywebsite.com', 'MyWebsite Admin');
    $mail->addAddress($emailId);     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($emailId);


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'MyWebsite password reset';
    $mail->Body    = '<h2>Hello!</h2><p>Forgotten your password?</p>
    <p>You have been sent this email because we received a request to reset the password to your MyWebsite account.</p>
    <p>To do this, please click the button below to enter a new password of your choice.</p>    
    <p>Regards,</p>
    <p>MyWebsite Support</p><p>'.$link.'</p>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'You have been sent this email because we received a request to reset the password to your MyWebsite account.';

    $mail->send();
    //echo 'An email was sent to ' . $emailId;
    include "password-reset-message.php";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
 

  }else{
    echo "Invalid Email Address. Go back";
  }
```

If I change this field from:

```
$mail->addAddress($emailId);     //Add a recipient
```

To this:

```
$mail->addAddress('email@mywebsite.com');     //Add a recipient
```

Then that works...

Comment: Did you check that `$emailId` actually contains `email@mywebsite.com`? From what you say it seems it doesn't.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So the $emailId is capturing the email address - I echo'd it out and it's showing (I will show below), but upon enabling debug I get this error

`Invalid address: (to): $emailId
An email was sent to xxxxxxx@gmail.com`

So it has the email in there but it's coming back as invalid

Comment: It looks like `$emailId` actually contains the string '$emailId'. Anyway, I cannot see where `$emailId` is given its value, that code is absent from your question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

I pass it here:

if(isset($_POST['password-reset-token']) && $_POST['email'])
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $loginsql, $passsql, "prpost_leaguehistory")
    or die("Could not connect to database");
     
    
  $emailId = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);

 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='" . $emailId . "'");
 
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

the form input:

 <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" class="form-control"  type="email" required>

Comment: I don't know how to make the edits formatted better

Comment: Please don't add chunks of code in comments, add them to the question so everybody can read it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware

Ok - I did do an echo of $emailId though so I can confirm that the data is being passed through there

Comment: I don't see a problem in that code. What I do notice is that you include the `$emailId` variable in the query string. That is a security risk. Please see: [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). This is a serious problem.

Comment: Yes, I believe you. I have no idea why the email is not sent.

Comment: One problem (though probably not the cause) – the fact that you're loading `PHPMailerAutoload.php` means that you're using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer. I recommend updating, and also learning how to use composer. (minor thing - `$emailId` injected into the SQL is at least escaped first - but it's easy to miss in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to $emailId not recieving its value. Try "echo $emailId" right before this part of your code and see if it has the email. Also try hardcoding the $emailId like this: $emailId = 'example@example.com';